# Admob Interstitial Ad fails to load

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to load `AdMob` `InterstitialAd` add when

1. App opens
2. Button is clicked
3. back is pressed

**Problems**

1. When app opens its shows ad failed to load (in catlog)
2. when back is pressed no ad is loaded
3. when button is clicked for the 1st time the ad loads but after 1st click, it never loads

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ```
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    Button mNewGameButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mNewGameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newgame_button);

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-5059726881726792/4446999064");
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            //Begin Game, continue with app
        }

        mNewGameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    //Begin Game, continue with app
                }
            }
        });

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                //Begin Game, continue with app
            }
        });

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
            .addTestDevice("D016E92D0D3266640328381D0A8BB622")//bluestacks
            .addTestDevice("CE34804F0BB3F1F2F409E6DDFB272C60").build();//s3
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-5059726881726792/4446999064");
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
            .addTestDevice("D016E92D0D3266640328381D0A8BB622")//bluestacks
            .addTestDevice("CE34804F0BB3F1F2F409E6DDFB272C60").build();//s3
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this ads in my application and working correctly.

Have a look at below example.

```
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    Button mNewGameButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.google_ad_mob);

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(<your ad unit id goes here>);
        final AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice("your test device id goes here");
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                super.onAdClosed();
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
            }
        });
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());

        mNewGameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newgame_button);

        newgame_button.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.newgame_button:
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> It always takes little time to load, hope you have imported SDK and manifest declaration(if not [check it here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)). Here is the detail explanation

1. Declare global variable

   ```
   private lateinit var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd
   ```
2. initialize the ad in onCreate of your activity

   ```
   mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
   mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
   mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
   ```
3. show ad

   ```
          if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
               mInterstitialAd.show()
           } else {
               Log.d("isLoaded", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.")
           }
   ```
4. adListener

   ```
   mInterstitialAd.adListener = object : AdListener() {
       override fun onAdClosed() {

           //go to second activity or do something
       }

       override fun onAdLoaded() {
           Log.d("zma interstitial", "loaded");
       }

       override fun onAdFailedToLoad(i: Int) {
           Log.w("AgeActivity", "onAdFailedToLoad:" + i)
       }
   }
   ```